# 1968 Beetle How to adjust adjustable beam

Tags: vw, beetle

I had the shop install an Airkewld adjustable beam on my 1968 Beetle. How do I now adjust the height of my car? Airkewld seems to have a few how-tos but they're not well written and apply to a complete install. Looks like I just have to loosen the two bolts but I'm not clear what happens after that.

Does the car have to be jacked from both sides? How does the beam move? Which way makes the car go up/down?

My goal is to reduce the amount of lowering. It seems like it's already as low as it'll go but I can't tell.

Beam:
http://www.airkewld.com/Ultimate-4-Narrowed-Adjustable-Front-Beam-2120-p/2120.htm

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Wish you were getting more action on this.   I want to see the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

It is as high as it will go. Loosen the jam nuts in the center of both the upper and lower tubes, a total of 4. Loosen the allen screws facing down equal amounts, upper and lower. Once you achieve the right height you want, tighten all the jam nuts. Then realign the vehicle. If the screw on the bottom is close to the ground, measure the amount of screw sticking out, remove the screw and cut that amount off the back of the screw. Re-Install and you will now have more ground clearance. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not really complete though for someone like me who's never done it before (and is not a mechanic). (1) Does the 'it' in "It is as high as it will go" refer to the car or the beam? (2) Are you saying, based on these pictures, my car cannot go any higher (by adjusting the beam anyway)? (3) Does the car need to be jacked up, to take the weight off the beam when loosening the nuts and adjusting the allen screws? (4) And so you're saying, to lower the car, turn the two allen bolts facing down counterclockwise? (5) Does the steering box need to be loosened first?

Answer (score -1):

I know it has been a couple of years, but I just now came across this article while looking at an explanation myself. I also found a video on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaThVu5rqSU that explains how it works that helped me understand how the Ultimate Beam works. I will try to answer your questions not by experience, but just by my common sense and finally understanding how the beam works.

1. Yes, it seems the beam is almost as high as it will go, but a little trick would be to take the lower jam nut off completely, loosen the hex enough to be able to use the jam nut on the inside of the adjuster cavity. That will allow you to raise it a little bit more. The video touches a bit on that.
2. I think based on the pictures your car could potentially go a little bit higher by putting the jam nut as explained above.
3. I would assume the car definitely needs to be jacked up to take the weight off the beam, at least just the front.
4. This is something the video will definitely help you understand.
5. I cannot answer that just yet, I will bounce this of my mechanic and will circle back, but this might give you a good starting point.